How should I use Nuxt Apollo outside of vue component or script setup to create repository for API calls?
I'm not a software engineer or nothing close to it and I'm in the process of learning to create a web app.
I'm playing with a NUXT app and Graphql, in which I'm trying to call a NESTjs API from outside  Vue component's script setup, by using NUXT Apollo composable functions in a separate .ts file. I'm trying to create a repository pattern or something to that effect to decouple API calls from vue components.
There are no issues with the API itself, it works just fine.
Here's an example very similar to what I have
Vue Component
<script setup lang="ts">
const searchInDB = async (search:string) => { 
  const res = await $api.repo.searchByName(search);
  console.log(res);
};
</script>

<template>
  <Button @click="searchInDB('example')" />
</template>

I'm making repositories available with this plugin
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const mods = {
    repo: new ApiRepository(),
  };

  return {
    provide: {
      api: mods,
    },
  };
});

This is the example Gql query.
const queries = {
  searchByName: gql`
    query SearchByName($name: String) {
      searchByName(name: $name) {
        _id
        name
      }
    }
  `,
}

When I call the API with useAsyncQuery, I can await the result and everything works fine, but NUXT will send a warning saying that I shouldn't use useAsyncData from the client side, that I should use $fetch instead.
export class ApiRepository {
   async searchByName(name: string) {
      const {data} = await useAsyncQuery(queries.searchByName, {name});
      if (!data.value) return [];
      return data.value;
   }
}

This will return the fetched value correctly, but will console.log the useAsyncData warning.
const res = await $api.repo.searchByName(search);
console.log(res);

Then, heeding that warning I try to call the API with useQuery. When returning that value to my Vue component it always returns undefined, since there is no "awaiting" for the result. I have tried to bypass this by using query.onResult(), but for that  to work I need to return a ref to the component that includes the result and then watcheffect() that ref inside that components so that I can set the final value with the contents of the response once they are available. Adding whatcheffect to the return value of every api call seems odd.
export class ApiRepository {
  async searchByName(name: string) {
    const res = ref();
    const query = await useQuery(queries.searchByName, {especialidad});
    query.onResult((result) => {
      res.value = result.data;
    });
    return {res};
  }
}

In the component this will return undefined, with no warning.
const {res} = await $api.repo.searchByName(search);
console.log(res);

If I wanted to get the final value after onResult resolves something, I would have to go
const {res} = await $api.repo.searchByName(search);
watchEffect(() => {
 console.log(res.value);
});

This would return and initial value while loading (with loading: true) and then a second value once loading:false with the final fetch result.
So, is it ok to just use useAsyncQuery for all my API calls, be it server or client side, so that I can get that pattern working with that composable?
What am I not understanding about the inner workings of NUXT or NUXT Apollo that would make useQuery work and return the result to the component once it has some results from the fetch?
